# Зачем используется прием - отрицательный margin, положительный padding

Tags: css, bootstrap, padding, margin, grid-layout

В коде boostrap нашел вот такой код.

```
.container-fluid {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
```

Для чего данный прием предназначен? Нельзя ли просто обойтись

```
.container-fluid {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.row {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Буду рад аргументированному ответу ссылкам на статьи на эту тему.

Comment: padding не бывает отрицательным

Comment: @Yuri да, однозначно дубликат. Методика очень распространённая, встречал неоднократно.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, только не пойму, неужели без неё нельзя? Отрицательные в старых плохо поддерживаются ведь

Comment: @Yuri да забили уже все на древние браузеры. Сколько процентов используют IE8 и ниже (кажется, там проблемы с отрицательными margin)

Comment: @Yuri на WordPress каждая первая коммерческая тема и каждый первый коммерческий плагин для визуального редактирования страниц используют эту методику. А рынок у этих продуктов - очень большой.

Comment: @Yuri - да что далеко ходить. Посмотрел стандартную тему WordPress - twentyseventeen, поставляемую по умолчанию с последней версией Wordpress. Вот:  .has-sidebar .entry-content blockquote.alignleft {
  margin-left: -20%;
 }

Comment: @KAGGDesign, ну вот, к примеру, делаю сайт для школы своей, а у нас там windows XP стоит, на которую IE8 - максимальный

Comment: @Yuri это очень узкий рынок ((

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61850/discussion-between-yuri-and-kagg-design).

Comment: Посмотрите, как это работает, в моем примере: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/690023/220220