# Оптимальная величина отрицательного отступа

Tags: css, padding, margin

Есть фреймворк Bootstrap. В этом фреймворке используется техника отрицательного отступа.

*Пример:*

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.row {
  margin: 0 -15px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.col {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 33.33333333%;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Так вот, откуда они взяли, что нужно брать отступ в 15px, а не 12? Как выбрать оптимальный отступ? От чего нужно отталкиваться?

Comment: Да ни от чего. На глаз 15px им нравится (да, наверное, и многим другим). причем имеется ввиду padding ***между колонками***.

Comment: Согласен с комментарием выше. 30рх между блоками выглядят и не близко, и не далеко. Под большинство задач подходит. Лично я не всегда использую такие отступы, если это grid-галерея, то, можно сделать небольшой отступ. Если же блоки большого размера с каким-то содержимым (текстом) и их не много (где-то 3 в ряд), то мелкий отступ будет смотреться не красиво.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот как это работает: padding на крайних колонках поглощается отрицательным margin. И три колонки идут во всю ширину вёрстки.

А самое смешное начинается, когда через @media меняем ширину колонки, на 50% или 100%. Благодаря `flex-wrap:wrap;` они переносятся на новую строку, и с padding и margin снова все в порядке.

То есть такая верстка сразу адаптивна.

В примере кода я изменил только ширину колонок во 2 и 3 ряду - и автоматически получил верстку в две и одну колонку.

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.row {
  margin: 0 -15px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  width: 33.3333333%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: none;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.cell {
  background: yellow;
  height: 100px;
}

#col-2 .col {
  width: 50%
}

#col-1 .col {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row" id="col-2">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row" id="col-1">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Суть вопроса немного иная. Человека интересовало, почему именно такие значения были выбраны, а не то, как это работает.

Comment: Я это понял и ответил в комментарии к самому вопросу. А мой ответ - это скорее продолжение и дополнение длинного чата сегодня по поводу отрицательных margin