# Как прижать блоки в родительском блоке. HTML

Tags: html, css

Задали сделать разметку по скрину:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все вроде пока получалось. Но вот секция маленьких новостей (где цифры 6) не получается.
Как сделать чтобы эти блоки не имели отступа слева и справа, но имели посередине, но при этом могли переноситься на новую строку при добавлении. Я попытался сделать, но не получилось, т.к нуб еще...
Была идея добавить `::last-child`, `first-child`, но не будут работать если задать `flex-wrap: wrap`;

```css
.upper {
    margin: 30px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: dimGray;
    padding: 0px;
}

.upper>div {
    width: 52px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: gray;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin: 5px 10px 5px 0px;
}

.upper>div:last-child {
   margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="upper">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: посмотрите как реализованы сетки (например bootstrap) - и сделайте также

Comment: "[padding на крайних колонках поглощается отрицательным margin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/690023/208926)"

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте про display: flex; Он позволяет задавать как будут выстраиваться элементы относительно сетки блока. Плюс позволяет задать блокам возможность растягиваться исходя из свободного места и заданных пропорций. А то что хотите вы - делается с помощью свойства justify-content: space-between;

```css
.news{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background:white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.news .item{
  margin: 10px;
  flex: 1 0 200px;
  height:200px;
  background:grey;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="news">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```